# Fragment gets destroyed 4 times when returning from Camera Intent

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a simple fragment that when user taps on the screen it will send an Intent to open the Camera app and then expect an image to be returned.

```
public void camera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

According to [Google developer](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) this should be all that is required.

After the picture has been taken and I press `SAVE` button in Camera app it returns back to my app.

I have set some breakpoints in `onDestroy()` and in `onActivityResult()`, it first destroys the fragment and creates a new one 2 times, then `onActivityResult()` is called and then it is .... destroyed again ... and created. So the image gets lost.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Running on Samsung S4

Comment: did you have any Exceptions on logcat

Answer (score 0):

Did u try using an intent extra called `EXTRA_OUTPUT` which will store the photo in given uri

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

startActivityForResult(intent , Request_Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty fix to it (dirty imo looks pretty weird)

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` add this parameter to your `Activity` that handles the Camera Intent:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

The `Activity` gets destroyed because of the orientation change in the transition to and from the Camera app... with this parameter it wont destroy.